# kohana 3.2 does not get 'get' request

Tags: php, kohana

After the transfer to a new server I'v got issue with get request.

for example

```
class Controller_Main extends Controller {
  public function action_testrequest()
  {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_GET);
    $this->auto_render = FALSE; // don't use layout
  }
}
```

and url `my-site/main/testrequest?query=test` returns empty array

at the same time `my-site/test.php?query=test` with content

```
<pre>
<?php
print_r($_GET);
```

returns

```
Array
(
[query] => test
)
```

Why is that?

I see the reason is in kohana, but I cannot find it.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with .htaccess

Solved replacing this:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT]
```

instead this:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

This [discussion](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/734/_get-empty/p1) helped me.